# how to open an activity with fragments from an other activity android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-intent

this is the code of the main activity

```
 package com.example.login;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Toast;

  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  DatabaseHelper helper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }

    public  void onBtnLoginInClick(View v){
    if(v.getId()==R.id.btnLoging){
        //Passing userName
        EditText UserNameET=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edname);
        String UserNameStr=UserNameET.getText().toString();
        //Passing Password
        EditText PasswordET=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Edpassword);
        String PasswordStr=PasswordET.getText().toString();


        String dbPassword=helper.LoginIn(UserNameStr);
        //Send UserName to Database to find it, and return Password
        //To compare it with Current Password from user input
        if(dbPassword.equals(PasswordStr)){
            Intent loginIntent=new Intent(this, accueil.class);
            loginIntent.putExtra("UserName",UserNameStr);
            loginIntent.putExtra("Password",PasswordStr);
            startActivity(loginIntent);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "UserName and Passwords dont match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


       }
       }

      public void onBtnSignUoClick(View v){
       if(v.getId()==R.id.btnSignUp){
        Intent SignUpIntent=new Intent(this,signup.class);
        startActivity(SignUpIntent);
        }
        }

        }
```

this is the activity that i want open and in this activity there is a menu of fragments

```
 package com.example.myapplication;

 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class accueil extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_accueil);
   }
```

when compiling my I code I didn't receive any error yet I couldn't relocate from Login my main activity to acceuil( an activity with a bottom_menu )

Comment: Did you have any exception or error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think you can't get dbPassword value. First try to put this line in onCreate Method

```
DatabaseHelper helper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

Then please check if you are getting the String **dbPassword** value. then I think the problem will be solved.